# qooxdoo's api-viewer run offline

Tags: api, qooxdoo

I dont know how to make qooxdoo's api-viewer run offline.

http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just run generate with the api target and you get a local copy of the api viewer wich also documeents your own project.

```
./generate.py api
```

then start a local web server in the  newly generated api directory

```
cd api
python -mSimpleHTTPServe
```

and open http://localhost:8000

Comment: I know but this not start locally. Failed to load Api data from the fiule system. The security settings of your browser may prohibit AJAX when using the file protocol try the http protocol instead. On my online-server it works

Comment: Ah that is because your browser prevents it ... you have to permit local filesystem access. It is a browser specific setting ...